# Qual a diferença entre substr() e mb_substr() em PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, symfony, substring

Estou desenvolvendo uma API usando *Symfony 6* onde eu salvo um campo do tipo longtext no MySql:

[image: Estutura da tabela]

Para salvar o texto nesse campo, eu estava dando um `substr($body,0,500)` para limitar o texto, pois é corpo de e-mail. Estava tudo funcionando até eu me deparar em um caso específico de um e-mail onde havia imagens.

Eu faço um tratamento nesse texto, removendo todas as *tags*, mas nesse e-mail só funcionava se eu fizesse *decode* pra *utf8*, porém quebrava os outros e-mails.

[Aqui há uma sugestão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984344/general-error-1366-incorrect-string-value-in-laravel-mysql) para substituir o `substr()` pelo `mb_substr()`, e quando fiz funcionou normalmente.

Minha dúida é *por que* isso? O que há de diferente nessas implementações para haver esse comportamento diferente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme pode ser visto nessa [lista de métodos](https://runebook.dev/pt/docs/php/-index-?q=substr) do *php 8.1*,

[`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) é uma função de manipulação de *String*; dessa forma, ela tratará o *texto* recebido da forma que ele "chegar" - ou seja, caso um caracter especial não seja convertido a um caracter válido, ele será replicado/utilizado dessa forma.

Já a `mb_substr()` também retorna a parte pesquisada de um texo, porém se trata de uma função *multibyte*. A importância desse tipo de função é que *strings* com caracteres especiais são *"maiores"* que as sem, o que pode ocasionar retornos incorretos no uso da `substr()`, por exemplo `substr("Häagen-Dazs", 0, 5) == "Häag"`

Outro exemplo está mostrado na [documentação da função](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-substr.php):

```
$str_utf8 = utf8_encode("Déjà_vu");
$str_utf8_0 = mb_strcut($str_utf8, 0, 4, "UTF-8"); // Déj
$str_utf8_1 = mb_strcut($str_utf8, 1, 4, "UTF-8"); // éj
$str_utf8_2 = mb_strcut($str_utf8, 2, 4, "UTF-8"); // éj
$str_utf8_3 = mb_strcut($str_utf8, 3, 4, "UTF-8"); // jà_
$str_utf8_4 = mb_strcut($str_utf8, 4, 4, "UTF-8"); // à_v
```

A *string* ("Déjà_vu") contém dois caracteres especiais (*"é"* e *"à"*) que são codificados com dois bytes; dessa forma a contagem se dá de forma diferente, o que faz com que as variáveis `$str_utf8_1` e `$str_utf8_2` exibam o mesmo retorno, mesmo com parâmetros diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, um pouco complicado entender na minha cabeça mas consegui ver a diferença. Essa questão de bytes me confundem um pouco ainda.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, o comportamento do `substr` pode mudar dependendo do `Function Overloading Feature` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).

Por isso, a resposta do @rLinhares só estará certa em versões do PHP 8+ ou em versões onde tal recurso não é usado.

---

O `substr` considera byte-a-byte, independente do *enconding* de texto usado. Logicamente, isso pode ser mudado usando o `Function Overloading Feature`. Por regra geral, NUNCA use o `substr`.

Já o `mb_substr` permite considerar o *enconding* do texto, como UTF-8, UTF-16 e afins. Portanto, ao invés de limitar a quantidade de bytes, limita a quantidade de caracteres. Mas, também pode considerar byte-a-byte usando `8bit` como *enconding*, o que garante o comportamento do `substr`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo complemento. No caso que me surgiu a dúvida estou usando o PHP 8.1